# IIS7 Url Rewrite Rule regex to make new path and strip extension

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

How can I create rewrite rule is to achieve the following:

before: `content/release/0.9.html`

after: `release-notes/0.9`

right now I'm having:

```
<rule name="Rewrite rule1 for content">
    <match url="^content/release/(.+)$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="release-notes/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

How can I get rid of the ".html" in the "after" output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<rule name="Rewrite rule1 for content">
    <match url="^content/release/(.+)\.html$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="release-notes/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```